# Insert tables into div via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbytagname

Hello I'm trying to insert multiple tables into a div.

I have a multiple tables in my document for e.g.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to select them:

```
table = document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE");
```

create div with class `"tablediv"`

and add each table to `"tablediv"` like:

```
<div class="tablediv">
   <table>
      ...
   </table>
</div>
```

Is it possible with pure js?

Comment: It's unclear, exactly what are you trying to do, but I'm almost sure that it's possible with pure JS...

Comment: Please provide more information about what you are trying to do. It's not clear if you want to move or copy the tables elsewhere.  Or you just want to select and modify them?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question. Hope it's clear now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
let divTable = document.createElement("div"); //create new <div>
divTable.id = "tablediv";

let tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table"); //HTMLCollection which is live, no need to delete "old tables"
while (tables.length > 0) divTable.append(tables[0]); //add every <table> to the new <div>

let body = document.querySelector("body"); //change to the preferred selector
body.append(divTable); //append new <div> to the selected Element, in this case <body>
```

Comment: This is what I need. One more question, Is it possible to append tables in the same places as before?

Comment: You would need a `<div>` (with an id hopefully) wrapping the original location of the tables. Then you select the tables the same way as i posted, but instead of creating a new element, you select it with `document.getElementById("your-original-wrapper-id")`.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible doing something like that

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE");
var div = document.getElementById('tablediv');
div.innerHTML += table;
```

Not sure about `document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE");` output you might need to use an extra attribute to access the html like innerHTML and you might need to use it in a loop if it's an array.

Answer (score 0):

run this solution. It has 4 tables. With a button-click, all the tables will be added to the DIV.

```js
function gatherTables(){
  var all_tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
  var tableCollectionDiv = document.getElementById('tablediv');
  
  tableCollectionDiv.innerHTML = '';
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(all_tables, a => {
    tableCollectionDiv.appendChild(a.cloneNode(true));
  });
}
```

```css
table td, table th {
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  padding: 6px;
}

#tablediv{
  background-color:  #8AC7DB;
  height: 500px;
}

body{
  background-color:#338BA8;
}

#tablediv > table{
  margin-top: 20px; 
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

button{
  background-color: #75E6DA;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>1a</th>
      <th>2a</th> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1a</td>
      <td>2a</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<br>
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>1b</th>
      <th>2b</th> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1b</td>
      <td>2b</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<br>
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>1c</th>
      <th>2c</th> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1c</td>
      <td>2c</td>
   </tr>
</table>


<br>
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>1d</th>
      <th>2d</th> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1d</td>
      <td>2d</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<br>
<button onclick="gatherTables()">Gather Tables Now</button>
<br>
<hr>
 DIV start
<div id="tablediv"></div>
 DIV end
```